# VGA-Display port dual monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, displayport

I have an HP mini desktop and two monitors which has only VGA port. For my data entry work need to connect these two monitor in dual setup mode. My mini desktop has one VGA port and two DisplayPort ports, D1 and D2.

[image: Photo of video ports]

I have two VGA male to female connector and VGA to DisplayPort adapter. Using these I managed to connect both monitors. Both monitors show the same screen and activities simultaneously. For my data entry work I need to see the document in one monitor and typing in another monitor

I have checked the display preferences - nothing happened.

[image: Display preferences]

Comment: So to confirm currently your screens are mirroring each other? Which operating system are you on? Windows/Mac?

Comment: Why is your display Mode in the second image defined as "Same As Primary"? That's perhaps the problem?

Comment: Yes. Thats the problem. Thank you...